# how can I run flask app in different port?

Tags: flask, localhost, port

I have a issue, problem is when I run flask app port :5000 it stops becouse:  Port 5000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port. but I dont know when i use it. I change port by :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

but it doesnt change anything.
also I use

```
export FLASK_APP=run.py
```

so I run app via flask run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options that might help.

If you are running your app using the flask run command in the terminal try adding this to the command

```
flask run -h localhost -p 8000
```

Another thing that might help is setting the run port in the environment variables like this

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
```

Let me know if either of these work.

Comment: Thanks, these realy help me. I use this
        flask run -h localhost -p 8000